# Can CD-RWs and DVD+/-RWs be mounted rw?

Tags: mount, dvd, cd, iso

@enzotib mentioned the following command

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /cdrom
```

Does this imply I can mount a CD or DVD in rw mode and use like a (real) filesystem? Does this work with the popular ISO-9660 filesystem, which is read-only by design? Will this create a multsession CD with one session per change (or per mount)?

Would this work (differently) on a ISO image file on a read/write filesystem?

Comment: In that context it was a Live USB pendrive, that by default is mounted on `/cdrom`.

Comment: @enzotib I see. Thank you. I still find the question interesting.

Comment: It may be possible with UDF and packet writing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_writing

Comment: @Anonymous Are you aware of any UDF implementation (on Linux)?

Comment: @Jan, the Linux kernel comes with support for UDF. DVD and Blu-ray use UDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use UDF file system as packet writing and it effectively works as USB drive (or as diskette). See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDF_File_System).

For example, BluRay discs as well as DVDs are usign UDF file system.
You just need to make it with UDFtools and mount it read/write.

Answer (score 1):

No they cannot.

To give a quick example why they cannot be mounted `rw` imagine mounting a blank cdr/cdrw, there is no file system on a blank cd, how do you specify one on mount then? How do you mount something to write on that has no valid file system?

Even nautilus with his integrated cd recording abilities does not follow that logic, the recording is not done automatically, it creates a tmp place to keep the files until you instruct to write them to a cd, blank or not.

Mounting a cdr/cdrw rw and writing on it as you with for example a USB disk is not possible.