# How to access read only files

Tags: dvd, read-only

I found an old DVD disc that i burned some stuff on almost 10 years ago. I have no use for that stuff anymore but i need the DVD disk to save some data. I tried deleting it the old fashiond way, and reformatting the disk with the Disk Utility app but no luck it always says that the content on the disk are read only files.

Comment: What kind of DVD disk is it? Is there a chance that it is rewritable? See this link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_recordable

Comment: Aternatively: https://askubuntu.com/questions/57995/can-cd-rws-and-dvd-rws-be-mounted-rw

Answer (score 2):

If your DVD is not rewritable (and it looks like that is the case), it won't be possible to delete anything in it. I suggest you to buy a USB Flash Drive, since these have become very cheap nowadays and have a lot more space than regular DVDs.